# Problems with the event treatment of a Button

Tags: android, button, event-listener

Something very weird is happening in my program. I try to use the button with the first program below (using an emulator) and the program did not even open. So I changed to the second version, using the android:OnClick, and it did not work either (the program opened, but in the click it crashed). Then I tried the third program, using android:onCLick and the instanciation of the EditText in the treatment function, and the program worked.

Can someone explain to me why the first two programs did not worked?

Edit: I noticed now that LogCat is pointing to the following error: error opening trace file: No such file oor directory (2), what is that? Can it have any relation to this error?
And if I comment the definition of the onClickListener to b1 the program do not crash anymore.

First code:

```
package app.projetnf33;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

String[] names;

EditText status;
EditText par1;
EditText par2;
EditText par3;

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;

Spinner spin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            status.setText("Connect");
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Second code

```
package app.projetnf33;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

String[] names;

EditText status;
EditText par1;
EditText par2;
EditText par3;

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;

Spinner spin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }   
}

public void treatment_connect(View v){
    status.setText("Connect");
}

public void treatment_persons(View v){
    status.setText("Persons");
}

public void treatment_lecture(View v){
    status.setText("Lecture");
}

public void treatment_execute(View v){
    status.setText("Execute");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Third code (which worked):

```
package app.projetnf33;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

String[] names;

EditText status;
EditText par1;
EditText par2;
EditText par3;

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;

Spinner spin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }   
}

public void treatment_connect(View v){
    status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
    status.setText("Connect");
}

public void treatment_persons(View v){
    status.setText("Persons");
}

public void treatment_lecture(View v){
    status.setText("Lecture");
}

public void treatment_execute(View v){
    status.setText("Execute");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Fragment_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tex_status" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>    

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/par1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/par1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/par2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/par2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/par3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/par3"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout> 


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_usb"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/connect"
            android:onClick="treatment_connect" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_computer"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/read"
            android:onClick="treatment_lecture" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/execution"
            android:onClick="treatment_execution" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_warning"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/disconnect"
            android:onClick="treatment_disconnect" />

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When an app crashes, your first step should be to look at LogCat which will show you a stacktrace that mosten times shows the exact line where, and the reason why the app crashed. If that does not work, try to debug the app. Set breakpoints at various places until you find out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

In the first and seconds layout you tried to call

```
status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

before

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

So you tried to reference a Button and EditText contained in the PlaceholderFragment layout before you created the fragment.

Comment: I already tried to put these lines after the if, and the program crashed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The views are in the fragment layout. It only becomes a part of the activity view hierarchy after the fragment transaction has been run. Your pending fragment transaction is executed in activity `super.onStart()` which comes only after `onCreate()`. In essence, you're calling `findViewById()` too early in the first two versions. The third version works because the `findViewById()` is in the click handler and gets invoked when the fragment is attached to the activity.

Usually you'd call `findViewById()` to set up listeners and so on at the earliest possibility in fragment `onCreateView()`, just after the fragment layout is inflated.